# Changing src value using jQuery not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to change out images within a small application.  I'm using anchor tags with click event.  Every time a anchor tag if clicked it updates a section for the html mark up to update a h1, a p tag, and an image.  Everything works, except for the image isn't being swapped out.

Here is my html for this small project:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a id="chilledMandy">Chilled Mandy</a></li>
    <li><a id="cuteMandy">Cute Mandy</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is the area where everything gets updated.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

            <div class="panel panel-danger">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h1 id="title">The Many Different Profiles of Mandy Mangum</h1>
                </div>
                    <div id="profile">
                        <h1 id="profile-title">This is the title area.</h1>
                        <img id="profile-image" src="images/chilledmandy.png">
                        <p id="profile-paragraph">This is the bio area<p>
                    </div><!-- end #profile -->
                </div><!-- end .panel-heading -->
            </div><!-- end .panel -->
    </div><!-- end .col-md-10 -->
  </div> <!-- end row -->
```

And this is my JQuery script

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#chilledMandy').click(function() {
            var title = 'Chilled Mandy';
            var paragraph = "This is a photo of chilled Mandy.  She seems to be enjoying herself outside on her patio while smiling at the camera.";
            var image = '\images/chilledmandy.png';

            var profileTitle = document.getElementById('profile-title');
            var profileParagraph = document.getElementById('profile-paragraph');
            var profileImage = document.getElementById('profile-image');

            profileTitle.innerHTML = title;
            profileParagraph.innerHTML = paragraph;
            profileImage.attr('alt', "We are adding this because we can.");
        });

        $('#cuteMandy').click(function() {
            var title = 'Cute Mandy';
            var paragraph = "This is a photo of cute Mandy.  She seems to be out and about with a few of her friends at a local place here in Austin, Texas.  As usual, when she is with her friends, Mandy seems to be at her happiest.";
            var image = '\images/cutemandy.png';

            var profileTitle = document.getElementById('profile-title');
            var profileParagraph = document.getElementById('profile-paragraph');
            var profileImage = document.getElementById('profile-image');

            profileTitle.innerHTML = title;
            profileParagraph.innerHTML = paragraph;
            profileImage.attr('alt', 'We are going to change this in the next major upgrade.');
        });
    });
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Try with delete this img tag, and append this markup (img) again on same place...

Comment: You don't appear to be doing anything with the var image

Comment: You never assign `image` to `profileImage.src`.

Comment: `.attr()` is a jQuery method, but `profileImage` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object. Aren't you seeing an error in the JS console from `profileImage.attr()`?

Comment: Thanks your suggestion worked.  I should have been using profileImahe.src

Answer (score 0):

You're never putting `image` into the `src`. Also, you have an extra `\` in the `image` string.

You're using a jQuery method to update the DOM element `profileImage`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#chilledMandy').click(function() {
        var title = 'Chilled Mandy';
        var paragraph = "This is a photo of chilled Mandy.  She seems to be enjoying herself outside on her patio while smiling at the camera.";
        var image = 'images/chilledmandy.png';

        var profileTitle = document.getElementById('profile-title');
        var profileParagraph = document.getElementById('profile-paragraph');
        var profileImage = document.getElementById('profile-image');

        profileTitle.innerHTML = title;
        profileParagraph.innerHTML = paragraph;
        $(profileImage).attr({
            'alt': "We are adding this because we can.",
            'src': image
        });
    });

    $('#cuteMandy').click(function() {
        var title = 'Cute Mandy';
        var paragraph = "This is a photo of cute Mandy.  She seems to be out and about with a few of her friends at a local place here in Austin, Texas.  As usual, when she is with her friends, Mandy seems to be at her happiest.";
        var image = 'images/cutemandy.png';

        var profileTitle = document.getElementById('profile-title');
        var profileParagraph = document.getElementById('profile-paragraph');
        var profileImage = document.getElementById('profile-image');

        profileTitle.innerHTML = title;
        profileParagraph.innerHTML = paragraph;
        $(profileImage).attr({
            'alt': 'We are going to change this in the next major upgrade.',
            'src': image
        });
    });
});
```